# How to use parseFloat to convert string to a number?

Tags: javascript, string, parsefloat

I was wondering how to use parseFloat with a string?. Example:

```
var N = 3.43;
var M = 43.37;
var subtotal = N + M;
subtotal=parseFloat("subtotal");
```

Comment: You don't have any string... :-?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `parseFloat` in your case.

To use `parseFloat` on a variable:

```
subtotal = parseFloat(subtotal); // No quotes here
```

Example:

```
var value = "3.14"; // String
var PI = parseFloat(value); // Float
```

OR

```
var PI = Number(value); // Float
```

OR

```
var PI = +value; // Float
```

Comment: For your example, I would not use `parseFloat`, but rather `Number` or even `+` : 
```var value = "3.14";
var valueAsNumber = Number(value);
var valueAsNumber2 = +value; 
``` Since `parseFloat` is much less performant. I would keep it to parse "33.333%", though

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes that you are passing inside `parsefloat`.

```
var N = 3.43;
var M = 43.37;
var subtotal = N + M;
subtotal=parseFloat(subtotal);
```